# Overwrite Failure - Databricks

Tags: amazon-s3, databricks, overwrite

From the latest runs, we observed a strange behaviour in writing the file to output S3. We generally overwrite the latest output to s3 and then it would overwrite all the old files in the folder. But, from past 2 successful runs we see that the files are not overwriting in s3 output but it is appending the data (no changes made in the code and it has mode=overwrite). The only change we made relates to Databricks jobs is to modify the cluster configuration. We are not sure whether this change is related to that as we followed this as a standard in all the other jobs.

Comment: Have you upgraded Databricks Runtime version? Like, going from 7.3 to 9.1 or 10.4?

Comment: I actually downgraded. Is that the issue? @AlexOtt

Comment: Add the code that you are using. And add information about changes you made

Comment: Initially we had issue with an error in SQL statement that is with correlated column which is not allowed in predicate, so we downgraded from 10.4 to 9.1. We didn't make any changes to the code. It fixed the issue however the overwrite is not happening as usual. I suspect it's an issue with the pathway but I do not know where or how to fix it. Thanks for your guidance, @AlexOtt